# MVC Spring Web Example

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I am looking for an easy to understand sliver of code that takes a parameter from a jsp page or html page passes it to an object that then passes it to a

Step 1. Web page sends id to -- >

controller object -- >

that passes it to -- > <--- This returns product code to a consumable object by the web page. So it then goes the other direction.

Example 2.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fetch/{id_code}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Product getProduct(@PathVariable("id") Integer productID) throws IFPApplicationException {
    Product product;
    try {
        logger.info("IFPProductServiceController::getProduct -->>>>");          
        logger.debug("Received request to get a product");
        // Delegate to service
        product = productService.get(productID);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IFPApplicationException("IFPProductServiceController::getProduct " + e.getMessage());
    }
    logger.info("<<<---- IFPProductServiceController::getProduct");     
    return product;
}
```

Comment: I understand your code but I have no idea what you're asking. Can you clarify a bit?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to return a ModelAndView instead of Product:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html

With the ModelAndView you can redirect to a jsp that will display your prododuct:

```
ModelAndView ret=new ModelAndView("/path/to/jsp");
ret.addObject("product",product);
return ret;
```

Then in your jsp you can display the product info with something like:

```
<body>
My product id: {product.id} 
My product description: {product.description}
</body>
```

Hope this is what you're looking for.